# ¿Mi código en PHP UPDATE para MYSQL está errado?

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero hacer una conexión para actualizar (modificar) mi base de datos, el problema es que cada que lo ejecuto solo cambia un valor y en 0.

```
$cant_mac=$_POST["cant_mac"];
$cant_hem=$_POST["cant_hem"];
$total=$_POST["total"];
$Fecha=$_POST["Fecha"];
$col_jaula = $_POST["col_jaula"];
$fil_jaula = $_POST["fil_jaula"];
$tip_cuy=$_POST["tip_cuy"];


$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE jaulas SET cant_mac = ? AND cant_hem = ? AND total= ? AND Fecha= ? WHERE col_jaula = ? AND fil_jaula= ? AND tip_cuy=?");

//UPDATE `jaulas` SET `cant_mac`=15,`cant_hem`=15,`total`=30,`Fecha`="2019-01-08 10:19:00" WHERE `col_jaula`="A" AND `fil_jaula`=1 AND `tip_cuy`="Adultos"

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "iiissis", $cant_mac, $cant_hem, $total, $Fecha, $col_jaula, $fil_jaula, $tip_cuy);

mysqli_execute($statement);

if(mysqli_execute($statement)){
    echo $cant_mac,$cant_hem,$total,$Fecha,$col_jaula,$fil_jaula,$tip_cuy;
    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
}else{
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

?>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los campos a actualizar debes separarlo por **coma**(**,**) y no por **AND**, asi:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE jaulas SET cant_mac = ?, cant_hem = ?,total= ? ,Fecha= ? WHERE col_jaula = ? AND fil_jaula= ? AND tip_cuy=?");
```

Comment: Gracias gracias,en serio, no soy tan bueno en las sintaxis talves por eso no note el error, personas preparadas como usted son lo mejor que le pudieron ocurrir a los foros!!! :D